# Firebase equivalent of MySQL in operator

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2

Assume my data looks something like this :

```
{
  "key_data" : {
    "1qwqwqwqwq" : {
      "map_id" : "9010",      
    },
    "1212wdwdw" : {
      "map_id" : "098",      
    },
    "1212dfefe" : {
      "map_id" : "5612",      
    },
    "1212eerer" : {
      "map_id" : "987",      
    }            
  }
}
```

In Firebase iOS Swift Library how do I get all `key_data` where `map_id` in `['9010','098']`?

Currently I am running this piece of code in a loop and appending the result into an array:

```
// for map_id in map_ids---
ref.queryOrderedByChild("map_id").queryEqualToValue(map_id)
                                 .observeEventType(.Value) { snapshot in
                                     //append into array
                                 }
```

Comment: There is no built-in `IN` operation in Firebase. This has been asked before, so I'll find a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [firebase equivalent to sql where in ()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560088/firebase-equivalent-to-sql-where-in)

Comment: Depending on the size of your dataset, (a few thousand) we have found an easy option is to read in the key_data node into Snapshot and then into an array. Filter using NSPredicate. Another option is to use ChildAdded event which auto-iterates over all of the children and just load the items of interest into an array as they are read in. It all depends on your dataset size.