# Query arrays values with Firebase

Tags: arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Is there any way to on Firebae to filter data in an array?

I have this model on my Firebase:

```
-KABIGeWnBMUKjLTcvp8  
  deviceToken:"7DE60240CB4B712F05A009F32358610C1327917E7E68409..."
  favorites
    0:"Masha"
    1:"moksha"
  name:"juan"
```

And the problem is that I can't find any method to get all "users" that contain a certain value on the "favorites" array field.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, that's not an option See [firebase equivalent to sql where in ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560088/firebase-equivalent-to-sql-where-in/29564075#29564075).

Instead: invert your data structure to make this query possible:

```
items_by_favorites
  "Masha"
    "-KABIGeWnBMUKjLTcvp8"
  "moksha"
    "-KABIGeWnBMUKjLTcvp8"
```

Now you can look up the item keys for Masha with a simple read: `ref.child('items_by_favorites/Masha')` and then load each item:

```
ref.child('items_by_favorites/Masha').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var key = childSnapshot.key();
    ref.child('items').child(key).once('value', function(itemSnapshot) {
      console.log(itemSnapshot.val());
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank. yesterday I wanted to chat with you. This solutions works that I expect.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your question is answered deep in the guide for [retrieving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html), which is where I got this answer.  It's under complex queries, then range queries, should you want more info.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(25).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

The basic idea is that you need to first order the reference by a common child value, and then call .equalTo() to end up with a query that yields what you want.

Also you can call order by child like

```
ref.orderByChild("height/sublevel")
```

To drill deeper in the tree.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't respond my question. I want to get all "artists" that match certain values on "favorites" array field.
EqualTo doesn't work on this array field

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your collection name').where('favorite', arrayContains: 'Masha').snapshot();
```