# Can I query Firebase with an array of ids?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm going to use GeoFire in order to store locations that relate to an "Invite Object" in my database. The GeoFire key for the location will be the Invites key in the database.

I would the like to query GeoFire for a list of locations near a location. Once I get all references back I would like to gather all the GeoFire Keys and then query for the actual Invite objects all at once. Is this possible ?

Also I'd like to limit my query to say 50 or 100 items at a time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: So if I have 50 items I want to load I have to do them one at a time ? I can't just request the all at once ?

Comment: Yes. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560088/firebase-equivalent-to-sql-where-in

Comment: do you happen to have an example of this in swift ?