# firebase snapshot key is displaying incorrect keys

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure like this 
[image]

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        database = firebase.database();
        var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Agents').child(newarray[i]).orderByKey();

        dbRef.on('value', newAgents,  errData);
    }
})

function newAgents(data) { 
    var container = document.getElementById("team"); 
    container.innerHTML = '';

    data.forEach(function(AgentSnap) { // loop over all jobs

        console.log(AgentSnap.key);
        var Agents = AgentSnap.val();
        var AgentCard = `
            <div class= "profilepics" id="${key}">
                <figure ><img src=${Agents.profilepicurl}><figcaption>${Agents.Fname}</figcaption></figure>
            </div>
         `;

        container.innerHTML += AgentCard;
    })
}
```

but a console log of the firebase datasnapshot key shows this

[image] 
how can I change the key from the child nodes to for example 19777873?

Comment: A likely culprit: I'd *strongly* recommend against using purely numeric keys for the Firebase Realtime Database. The SDK will automatically try to coerce it into an array. What if you prefix with an underscore, e.g. `_12354666`

Comment: ok I will generate alphanumeric keys

Comment: @MichaelBleigh While I agree with your recommendation, I doubt it's the cause of the problems for this data set. The data is extremely sparse and the SDK is smart enough to detect that this is *not* an array.

Comment: @Ola: it looks like you're attaching your listener too low in the tree. Can you edit your question to include the code where you attach a listener and call `newAgents` with the snapshot?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the listener. The listener is actually located in another function.

Answer (score 0):

You attach your listener to a single agent:

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Agents').child(newarray[i]).orderByKey();
```

This means that the snapshot that is passed to your callback will contains the properties of a single agent. Then in your listener you loop over the children of the snapshot. This means you end up iterating over `AuthId`, `Fname`, `Lname`.

To get all agents, attach the listener to `/Agents`:

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Agents').orderByKey();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, the reason why I used newarray[i] is because I have sets of IDs that have been assigned to newarray and I was thinking that adding [I] will cause it to find each ID of newarray consecutively in the database. if I just reference .child('Agents'), it displays everything under agent which is too much for what I am looking for . I just want it to display only what matches what is in newarray

Comment: Firebase doesn't have a way to return a list of items by their key. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560088/firebase-equivalent-to-sql-where-in