# Firebase Query to select upon a key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all the posts that have the key "type" equal to 1 or 2
this code doesn't work

```
@Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    return databaseReference.child("posts").orderByChild("type").equalTo(1).orderByChild("type").equalTo(2);  
}`
```

but this one works for only type 1:

```
@Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    return databaseReference.child("posts").orderByChild("type").equalTo(1);   
}
```

How can I have posts that contains both values for the key "type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a range filter (Edited):

```
return databaseReference.child("posts")
                        .orderByChild("type")
                        .startAt(1)
                        .endAt(2)
```

But this will only work for filtering on a consecutive range (like here). It won't work if you want items with type `1` or `3`, but not with `2`. Firebase doesn't support such multi-operand queries.

Also see:

- [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)
- [firebase equivalent to sql where in ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560088/firebase-equivalent-to-sql-where-in)
- [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)