# Firebase query for multiple where condition

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need equivalent query of

> SELECT PlayerName FROM GameScores 
>   WHERE Department = 'HR' OR Department = 'IT' OR Department = 'Marketing'

In Firebase for android , I don't want multiple call, just one request and get all data that match with where clause key. How I can do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @Martin: the question you link is about filtering on multiple properties, while this one wants to filter on multiple values of a single property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to filter a property on multiple values in Firebase is if those values are in a range. For example, you could get all items matching your values with:

```
ref.child("GameScores")
   .orderByChild("Department")
   .startAt("HR")
   .endAt("Marketing")
```

The problem with this is that it also matches scores from other departments whose name is between `HR` and `Marketing`, such as

There is no way in either the Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore to pass multiple separate values into a query. You will have to execute a separate query for each value and merge them client-side.

Also see:

- [firebase equivalent to sql where in ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560088/firebase-equivalent-to-sql-where-in)

Comment: Thanks Frank I tried your solution and i have restructure my db