# How I can get all the values of nodes present in a table?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, nodes

[Here's my database and I want to get all the values of all the nodes in Users table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWWkb.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android firebase database: how to get all nodes that are in a set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625252/android-firebase-database-how-to-get-all-nodes-that-are-in-a-set-of-values)

Comment: So you want to get the data under each child of the `Users` node? What is the programming language you're using? Java or Kotlin? Please respond with @AlexMamo