# Android - Realtime Database multi child query?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to write a code like this.

```
Select column1,column2,column3 FROM WHERE column1="value1" OR column1="value2" OR column1="value3";
```

How should I write similar codes for Realtime Database? Can you write sample code to read the areas I draw in red? thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560088/firebase-equivalent-to-sql-where-in and more from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+or+query

Answer (score 0):

You can't write logical OR queries for Realtime Database.  You will need to perform three different queries, one for each child.  Each query will also fetch then **entire** contents of that node.  It's not possible to specify only certain nested children.

Comment: hmm. I have to write queries in order for each child and add them in a single array. Does it make sense? after all, every child carries the same structure.

Comment: Yes you will have to do that.